# Table name as variable in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I tried running the following query, which sets the table name through a variable:

```
--/* 
declare
    tbl varchar2(20) := 'TABLE_NAME';
begin
    execute immediate 'select * from ' || tbl || ' where rownum <=1';
end;
--*/
```

But it is not working.

This query is based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11622233/oracle-sql-variables-used-in-place-of-table-names)

What am I missing here?

Comment: Well, did you read the selected answer to the question you referenced?

Comment: Oh sorry, that was the wrong reference. Thanks.

Comment: Just read it again. Do I need to include the INTO part of the EXECUTE IMMEDIATE statement?

Comment: @Alan Yes, you need the Into part. You can output that value, use it, return it if you write a function...