# Insert a var like table in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm new in `PL/SQL` and I'm trying to do the following:

Via a var, insert it like a TABLE:

```
DECLARE
  VL_TABLE_NAME VARCHAR2(100); 
BEGIN
  VL_TABLE_NAME := 'TABLE_NAME';
  SELECT *
  FROM VL_TABLE_NAME;
```

Do you have any idea how to do this?

Comment: Because a table name and fields can't be a variable.  This concept is an unsupported syntax..  To make it work, you would have to make the entire select statement using dynamic SQL ( a variable) and then use the execute VL_SQL.  so something like `VL_SQL := 'SELECT * FROM ' || VL_TABLE_NAME || ';'` then `Execute VL_SQL`

Comment: Example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11622233/oracle-sql-variables-used-in-place-of-table-names More on [Dynamic SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10795/adfns_dy.htm)  or use [Synonyms](https://community.oracle.com/thread/2134930?tstart=0) but not quite what you're after

Comment: Thank you @xQbert . It works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select from a parametrized table, you need to build your query as a string and execute it afterwards. To "catch" the return in a variable, you also need to specify a "INTO" clause.

```
DECLARE
 tableName varchar2(40);
 res number;
BEGIN
  tableName := 'USER_TABLES';

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT count(*) FROM ' || tableName || ' WHERE 1=1'  INTO res;
  dbms_output.put_line(res);
END;
```

Answer (score 2):

I have an idea. You may use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`

```
DECLARE
  VL_TABLE_NAME VARCHAR2(100); 
  V_SQL VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
  VL_TABLE_NAME := 'TABLE_NAME';
  V_SQL := 'SELECT * FROM ' || VL_TABLE_NAME;  
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE V_SQL;
END;
```

More information about this clause read here https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/dynamic.htm

Also you may use `DBMS_SQL` 
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/dynamic.htm#LNPLS011