# Unable to use PL/SQL table name as a variable in PL/SQL procedure?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm unable to use table name as a variable in my PL/SQL procedure, the table here change every month, in my code, there are two table name variable from `' || v_PRM_TABLE1 || '` and `from ' || v_PRM_TABLE2 || '` I tried to use the syntax that was mentioned in this question but not working for me

[Oracle SQL: variables used in place of table names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11622233/oracle-sql-variables-used-in-place-of-table-names)

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON SIZE 1000000;

DECLARE
--FIRST DAY YEAR
v_SG_FYEAR VARCHAR(50);
--FIRST DAY MONTH
v_SG_FMNTH VARCHAR(50);
--FIRST DAY START DAY
v_SG_FDAY VARCHAR(50);

--LAST DAY MONTH
v_SG_LYEAR VARCHAR(50);
--LAST DAY MONTH
v_SG_LMNTH VARCHAR(50);
--LAST DAY START DAY
v_SG_LDAY VARCHAR(50);

v_JOBID number(20);
v_PRM_TABLE1 varchar(200);
v_PRM_TABLE2 varchar(200);
BEGIN
/*Getting last JOB_ID*/
SELECT MAX(JOB_ID) INTO v_JOBID from ON_SGSN_TAPOUT;
case when v_JOBID IS NULL then v_JOBID:=1;
 when v_JOBID IS NOT NULL THEN 
      SELECT MAX(JOB_ID)+1 INTO v_JOBID FROM ON_SGSN_TAPOUT;
 END CASE;

v_SG_FYEAR:=TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MM')-1,'YYYY');
v_SG_FMNTH:=TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MM')-1,'MM');
v_SG_FDAY:='01';

v_SG_LYEAR:=TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MM')-1,'YYYY');
v_SG_LMNTH:=TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MM')-1,'MM');
v_SG_LDAY:=TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MM')-1,'DD');

v_PRM_TABLE1:='prmdb.CDR_TAPOUT_'||v_SG_FYEAR||v_SG_FMNTH||'@prmdb';
v_PRM_TABLE2:='prmdb.CDR_TAPOUT_'||TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYYMM')||'@prmdb';

FOR REC IN (
        select * from(
        select * from (
        SELECT TO_CHAR(START_TIME,'YYYYMMDD') AS "SGSN_DATE",
        SUM(SUM_UP_DOWN/1024/1024) SGSN_MB
        FROM OPS$DEBIT.FACT_HUA_SGSN_INBOUND@RADB 
        WHERE START_TIME BETWEEN TO_DATE(v_SG_FMNTH||'/'||v_SG_FDAY||'/'||v_SG_FYEAR||' 
'||'00:00:00','mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
        AND  TO_DATE(v_SG_LMNTH||'/'||v_SG_LDAY||'/'||v_SG_LYEAR||' '||'23:59:59','mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
        GROUP BY TO_CHAR(START_TIME,'YYYYMMDD')) A
        left outer join 
        (
        select PRM_MNTH,PRM_ACT_MB,PRM_RND_MB,PRM_CHRG_USD from(
        select PRM_MNTH,SUM(PRM_ACT_MB) PRM_ACT_MB,SUM(PRM_RND_MB) PRM_RND_MB,SUM(PRM_CHRG_USD) PRM_CHRG_USD  from(
        select substr(START_TIME,1,8) PRM_MNTH,sum(TOTAL_BYTE)/1024/1024 PRM_ACT_MB, sum(charged_units)/1024/1024 PRM_RND_MB, sum(tap_fee_usd) PRM_CHRG_USD
        from ' || v_PRM_TABLE1 || '
        where start_time between v_SG_FYEAR||v_SG_FMNTH||'01000000' and v_SG_LYEAR||v_SG_LMNTH||v_SG_LDAY||'235959' 
        and CDR_TYPE in ('GPRSO')
        group by substr(START_TIME,1,8)
        UNION ALL
        select substr(START_TIME,1,8) PRM_MNTH,sum(TOTAL_BYTE)/1024/1024 PRM_ACT_MB, sum(charged_units)/1024/1024 PRM_RND_MB, sum(tap_fee_usd) PRM_CHRG_USD
        from ' || v_PRM_TABLE2 || '
        where start_time between v_SG_FYEAR||v_SG_FMNTH||'01000000' and v_SG_LYEAR||v_SG_LMNTH||v_SG_LDAY||'235959' 
        and CDR_TYPE in ('GPRSO')
        group by substr(START_TIME,1,8))
        group by
        PRM_MNTH)
            ) B
        ON A.SGSN_DATE=B.PRM_MNTH)
        )
        LOOP
        INSERT INTO ON_SGSN_TAPOUT values(v_JOBID,REC.SGSN_DATE,REC.SGSN_MB,REC.PRM_MNTH,REC.PRM_ACT_MB,REC.PRM_RND_MB,REC.PRM_CHRG_USD,REC.PRM_ACT_MB-REC.SGSN_MB,SYSDATE);
        commit;
        END LOOP;  
END;
```

Comment: You're still using static sql, please read linked question carefully again.

Comment: I have used the same syntax used for the variable name `' || v_PRM_TABLE1 || '`, my you please let me know what you mean by static SQL? I have other variables in my query all of them working fine except the table name.

Comment: @OsamaAl-Banna . . . Hint:  `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`.

Comment: Static SQL: `select 1 into varResult from dual;` Dynamic SQL: `execute immediate 'select 1 from '||varTableName into varResult;`.

Comment: I recommend the Oracle documentation. I find it very clear and complete. Refer to [PL/SQL Dynamic SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/lnpls/dynamic-sql.html#GUID-7E2F596F-9CA3-4DC8-8333-0C117962DB73)

Comment: I will try to re-write the script in a dynamic way check again.

Comment: Looks like the table name is the only thing that requires dynamic sql. If so then there is a much easier, and more efficient way. Create a pseudo table name use that name as synonym for the actual table. Write static SQL, referring to the synonym. Now write a script that runs monthly to update the synonym.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I really feel it's getting to complex can you share with an example that how to use execute immediate with FOR LOOP  and table name as a variable.

Comment: @0xdb my code will return multiple column result does `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` support that ?

Comment: @OsamaAl-Banna Yes, e.g.: `cols varchar2(400) := '1 col1, 2 col2'; execute immediate 'select '||cols||' from dual;' into val1, val2;`

Comment: @0xdb as you can see my statement too long, can I  use `select  *  from table`  also I have to store the result into a variable the result will be too long what is the variable `data type` for the result variable?

Comment: @Belayer that is a good solution but I don't privilege to create a synonym , so I think dynamic SQL is the only way.

Comment: Then go to your DBAs. Have them create the initial synonym ans monthly change script in their schema and grant execute to you, or better your application schema. Keep in mind you and the they are a team charged **together** with providing the best solution.  The best excuse for building a poor solution is "I don't have authority to do it correctly."

Comment: @Belayer I solve without synonym, I prefer my script to be independent and does not depend on synonym or a job that continuously updating, but anyway thanks for your suggestion it might be useful in other scenarios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it without using `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`, I don't know if this solution considered dynamic SQL or not, the hardest part was concatenating this big complex query into string variable.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON SIZE 1000000;
DECLARE
--FIRST DAY YEAR
v_SG_FYEAR VARCHAR(50);
--FIRST DAY MONTH
v_SG_FMNTH VARCHAR(50);
--FIRST DAY START DAY
v_SG_FDAY VARCHAR(50);

--LAST DAY MONTH
v_SG_LYEAR VARCHAR(50);
--LAST DAY MONTH
v_SG_LMNTH VARCHAR(50);
--LAST DAY START DAY
v_SG_LDAY VARCHAR(50);

v_JOBID number(20);
v_PRM_TABLE1 varchar(200);
v_PRM_TABLE2 varchar(200);
--craeting a data type
type t_rec is record(SGSN_DATE VARCHAR2(200),
                 SGSN_MB VARCHAR2(200),
                 PRM_MNTH VARCHAR2(200),
                 PRM_ACT_MB VARCHAR2(200),
                 PRM_RND_MB VARCHAR2(200),
                 PRM_CHRG_USD VARCHAR2(200));
v_REC t_rec;
C1 sys_refcursor;
v_sql varchar2(32767);
BEGIN
/*Getting last JOB_ID*/
SELECT MAX(JOB_ID) INTO v_JOBID from ON_SGSN_TAPOUT;
case when v_JOBID IS NULL then v_JOBID:=1;
 when v_JOBID IS NOT NULL THEN 
      SELECT MAX(JOB_ID)+1 INTO v_JOBID FROM ON_SGSN_TAPOUT;
 END CASE;
v_SG_FYEAR:=TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MM')-1,'YYYY');
v_SG_FMNTH:=TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MM')-1,'MM');
v_SG_FDAY:='01';
v_SG_LYEAR:=TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MM')-1,'YYYY');
v_SG_LMNTH:=TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MM')-1,'MM');
v_SG_LDAY:=TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MM')-1,'DD');
v_PRM_TABLE1:='prmdb.CDR_TAPOUT_'||v_SG_FYEAR||v_SG_FMNTH||'@prmdb';
v_PRM_TABLE2:='prmdb.CDR_TAPOUT_'||TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYYMM')||'@prmdb';

/*putting the SQL query into a variable*/
v_sql:='select * from('||
   'select * from ('||
   'SELECT TO_CHAR(START_TIME,''YYYYMMDD'') AS "SGSN_DATE",'||
   'SUM(SUM_UP_DOWN/1024/1024) SGSN_MB'||
   ' FROM OPS$DEBIT.FACT_HUA_SGSN_INBOUND@RADB'|| 
   ' WHERE START_TIME BETWEEN 
TO_DATE('''||v_SG_FMNTH||'/'||v_SG_FDAY||'/'||v_SG_FYEAR||' 
'||'00:00:00'||''','||'''mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'||''')'||
' AND  TO_DATE('''||v_SG_LMNTH||'/'||v_SG_LDAY||'/'||v_SG_LYEAR||' 
'||'23:59:59'||''','||'''mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'||''')'||
' GROUP BY TO_CHAR(START_TIME,''YYYYMMDD'')) A '||
'left outer join '|| 
'('||
'select PRM_MNTH,PRM_ACT_MB,PRM_RND_MB,PRM_CHRG_USD from ('||
'select PRM_MNTH,SUM(PRM_ACT_MB) PRM_ACT_MB,SUM(PRM_RND_MB) 
 PRM_RND_MB,SUM(PRM_CHRG_USD) PRM_CHRG_USD  from ('||
 'select substr(START_TIME,1,8) PRM_MNTH,sum(TOTAL_BYTE)/1024/1024 PRM_ACT_MB, 
 sum(charged_units)/1024/1024 PRM_RND_MB, sum(tap_fee_usd) PRM_CHRG_USD'||
 ' from '|| v_PRM_TABLE1 ||
 ' where start_time between '''||v_SG_FYEAR||v_SG_FMNTH||v_SG_FDAY||'000000'' and 
 '''||v_SG_LYEAR||v_SG_LMNTH||v_SG_LDAY||'235959'''|| 
 ' and CDR_TYPE in (''GPRSO'') '||
 ' group by substr(START_TIME,1,8) '||
 ' UNION ALL '||
 ' select substr(START_TIME,1,8) PRM_MNTH,sum(TOTAL_BYTE)/1024/1024 PRM_ACT_MB, 
 sum(charged_units)/1024/1024 PRM_RND_MB, sum(tap_fee_usd) PRM_CHRG_USD '||
 ' from '||v_PRM_TABLE2||
 ' where start_time between '''||v_SG_FYEAR||v_SG_FMNTH||v_SG_FDAY||'000000'' and 
 '''||v_SG_LYEAR||v_SG_LMNTH||v_SG_LDAY||'235959'''|| 
 ' and CDR_TYPE in (''GPRSO'')'||
 ' group by substr(START_TIME,1,8))'||
 ' group by'||
 ' PRM_MNTH)'||
 ') B'||
 ' ON A.SGSN_DATE=B.PRM_MNTH)';  
   OPEN C1 FOR v_sql;
   LOOP
   FETCH C1 INTO v_REC;
   EXIT WHEN C1%NOTFOUND;
   dbms_output.put_line(v_REC.SGSN_DATE||' '||v_REC.SGSN_MB||' '||v_REC.PRM_MNTH||' 
   '||v_REC.PRM_ACT_MB||' '||v_REC.PRM_RND_MB||' '||v_REC.PRM_CHRG_USD||' '||SYSDATE);
   END LOOP;
 END;
 /
```

Comment: Yep, sub-optimal solution and a maintenance nightmare. it is not a  continuous running update job, scheduled once a month. But I don't have to maintain it. Good Luck.